# Facebook Places API 500 result limit

Tags: facebook, limit, facebook-opengraph

Facebook OpenGrap API limit results of [id]/checkins to 500. Is there are way to retrieve more than 500. Example if I want to retirve all the place someone has checkin for year 2011. What are possible available methods. Is there a premium service provided by Facebook.

Regards,
Waruna.

Comment: The API should return 500 places and a paging url to get the next 500 places.

Comment: So using paging URL I should be able to access all places user had checkin?

Comment: I put this in a answer, check it out! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the open grpah documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) describes, there should be a "paging" object at the end of the api response if there is more content than you could load at one time. You can test this by clicking the example links inthe documentation. So, the solution is: Loop your requests until there is no "next" property in the "paging" object of the response.

Also there are possibilites to [batch your requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/), maybe this is also useful for you.